# iOS: Creating a rectangle with holes using Core Graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics, mapkit

I have an `MKMapView` where I want to grey out parts of the map. More specifically, I want to have some circles and rectangles which are displayed normally and the rest of the map has a semi-transparent grey layer. Something like this:

[image]

For that, I think that I should subclass `MKOverlay` and `MKOverlayRenderer`. As Apple suggests, in my `MKOverlayRenderer` subclass, I should override the [`drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayRenderer_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKOverlayRenderer/drawMapRect:zoomScale:inContext:) method, and draw my stuff using Core Graphics. My question is how can I draw the following with Core Graphics?

[image]

I have spent some hours looking at masking and clipping using Core Graphics, but I haven't found anything similar to this. The [QuartzDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_34) has some examples of clipping and masking. I guess clipping with either the even-odd or nonzero winding number rules won't work for me, as the rectangles and circles are dynamic. I think I have to create a mask somehow, but I can't figure out how. The QuartzDemo [creates a mask out of an image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/QuartzDemo_QuartzClipping_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531-QuartzDemo_QuartzClipping_m-DontLinkElementID_12). How could I create a mask using rectangles and circles? Is there any other way I could approach this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I worked it out myself. I have to create my own mask. This is done by drawing the "hole" shapes, outputting this to an ImageRef, and inverting this ImageRef to output the mask. Here is a code snippet that could work if you add it in the [QuartzDemo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) project->`QuartzClipping.m`->`QuartzClippingView` class, at the end of the `drawInContext` method.

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context {

    // ...

    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    // dimension of the square mask
    int dimension = 20;

    // create mask
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(dimension, dimension), NO, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef newContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draw overlapping circle holes
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(newContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(newContext, CGRectMake(0, 7, 10, 10));

    // draw mask
    CGImageRef mask = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // the inverted mask is what we need
    CGImageRef invertedMask = [self invertMask:mask dimension:dimension];

    CGRect rectToDraw = CGRectMake(210.0, height - 290.0, 90.0, 90.0);

    // everything drawn in rectToDraw after this will have two holes
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rectToDraw, invertedMask);

    // drawing a red rectangle for this demo
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectToDraw);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}

// taken from the QuartzMaskingView below
- (CGImageRef)invertMask:(CGImageRef)originalMask dimension:(int)dimension{
    // To show the difference with an image mask, we take the above image and process it to extract
    // the alpha channel as a mask.
    // Allocate data
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:dimension * dimension * 1];
    // Create a bitmap context
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate([data mutableBytes], dimension, dimension, 8, dimension, NULL, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaOnly);
    // Set the blend mode to copy to avoid any alteration of the source data
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
    // Draw the image to extract the alpha channel
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, dimension, dimension), originalMask);
    // Now the alpha channel has been copied into our NSData object above, so discard the context and lets make an image mask.
    CGContextRelease(context);
    // Create a data provider for our data object (NSMutableData is tollfree bridged to CFMutableDataRef, which is compatible with CFDataRef)
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)data);
    // Create our new mask image with the same size as the original image
    return CGImageMaskCreate(dimension, dimension, 8, 8, dimension, dataProvider, NULL, YES);
}
```

Any easier/more efficient solution is welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to setup a context with transparency, draw the skinny rectangles and circles without stroking them, draw a rectangle border around the whole context, and then fill the shape with the darker color. You'll need to look into [fill order rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106) to make sure that the larger space is what is filled rather than the smaller joined shapes.

> I guess clipping with either the even-odd or nonzero winding number rules won't work for me, as the rectangles and circles are dynamic.

This shouldn't matter.

Comment: I think this does matter. What if I have two overlapping circles? I don't want any part of them to be filled with colour. Both with the "nonzero winding number" and the "even-odd" rules, the overlapping part gets filled. I think I have to draw my custom mask.